# How to redirect the user to another location after login WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make a plugin, I need to redirect user to another page or location instead of dashboard. I tried few action or filter hook but none of them work for me. Please help me by sharin code or tutorial.

```php
function redirect_function() {
  wp_redirect('http://google.com');
  die();
}
add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_function');
// add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_function', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Which action or filter hooks did you try? Please add the code you tried to the question

Comment: To add to jrswgtr's comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You can try code below:

```
function redirect_on_login() {
    $some_url = 'some url';
    wp_redirect( $some_url );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'redirect_on_login', 1 );
```

Also you can check the [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/)

Comment: @SumanBiswas Probably the problem is the priority of the action. The plugin you uninstalled might have an action with a lower priority number, so it will be executed before yours. Try to set it to 1: `add_action( 'wp_login', 'redirect_on_login' , 1);`

Comment: Yes, there was a priority issue. But currently, its working without pass priority params `add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_function')`